# Apache Sling Authentication Service Anonymous Password Change Disabled Access to Login

Tags: aem, anonymous, livecycle, crx

I made a change to the Apache Sling Authentication Service Anonymous account user password and enabled anonymous access. I also went into the anonymous user and changed the account password to match.

Unfortunately after this change, access to the login page was locked out with a continuous push to http://localhost:8080/um/login and a 403 error with a "This website requires you to log in." for any URL related to AEM. The JEE links (LiveCycle) still work. i.e.: /adminui.

Is there a way to "factory reset" both the values of the Apache Sling Authentication Service?

> 17:07:24,613 ERROR
>   [com.adobe.idp.um.provider.authentication.LDAPAuthProviderImpl]
>   (Thread-272) UserM:GENERIC_SEVERE: [Thread Hashcode: 1678680974] User
>   Name or Password is null 17:07:24,644 WARN 
>   [com.adobe.idp.um.businesslogic.authentication.AuthenticationManagerBean]
>   (Thread-272) Authentication failed for user [anonymous] (Scheme -
>   Username/Password) Reason: Username or password is incorrect . Refer
>   to debug level logs for category
>   com.adobe.idp.um.businesslogic.authentication for further details
>   17:07:24,800 ERROR
>   [com.adobe.idp.um.provider.authentication.LDAPAuthProviderImpl]
>   (Thread-272) UserM:GENERIC_SEVERE: [Thread Hashcode: 1678680974] User
>   Name or Password is null 17:07:24,816 WARN 
>   [com.adobe.idp.um.businesslogic.authentication.AuthenticationManagerBean]
>   (Thread-272) Authentication failed for user [anonymous] (Scheme -
>   Username/Password) Reason: Username or password is incorrect . Refer
>   to debug level logs for category
>   com.adobe.idp.um.businesslogic.authentication for further details
>   17:07:24,879 ERROR
>   [com.adobe.idp.um.provider.authentication.LDAPAuthProviderImpl]
>   (Thread-272) UserM:GENERIC_SEVERE: [Thread Hashcode: 1678680974] User
>   Name or Password is null 17:07:24,894 WARN 
>   [com.adobe.idp.um.businesslogic.authentication.AuthenticationManagerBean]
>   (Thread-272) Authentication failed for user [anonymous] (Scheme -
>   Username/Password) Reason: Username or password is incorrect . Refer
>   to debug level logs for category
>   com.adobe.idp.um.businesslogic.authentication for further details
>   17:07:25,050 ERROR
>   [com.adobe.idp.um.provider.authentication.LDAPAuthProviderImpl]
>   (Thread-272) UserM:GENERIC_SEVERE: [Thread Hashcode: 1678680974] User
>   Name or Password is null 17:07:25,066 WARN 
>   [com.adobe.idp.um.businesslogic.authentication.AuthenticationManagerBean]
>   (Thread-272) Authentication failed for user [anonymous] (Scheme -
>   Username/Password) Reason: Username or password is incorrect . Refer
>   to debug level logs for category
>   com.adobe.idp.um.businesslogic.authentication for further details
>   17:07:25,144 ERROR
>   [com.adobe.idp.um.provider.authentication.LDAPAuthProviderImpl]
>   (Thread-272) UserM:GENERIC_SEVERE: [Thread Hashcode: 1678680974] User
>   Name or Password is null

Answer (score 1):

In order for these changes to take effect the AEM instance needs to be restarted.